# How can I make all panels resize equally when form is maximized

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently when I maximize my form it resizes as it looks below.

[image]

This is due to the anchoring element stretching the two bottom panels on the left as well as causing a gap on the right since nothing is anchored right. I could fill the gap on the right by anchoring the right most panel however that would just cause it to be wider than all the other panels.

What I want is an equal resizing of the panels when the form is maximized as depicted below

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TableLayoutPanel`:
Add `TableLayoutPanel` to the form and set `Dock = Fill`
Add 2 rows to the `TableLayoutPanel` (by default there is already two)

- Row 1 - Height = 50%
- Row 2 - Height = 50%

Add 4 columns to the `TableLayoutPanel` (by default there is already two)

- Column 1 - Width = 25%
- Column 2 - Width = 25%
- Column 3 - Width = 25%
- Column 4 - Width = 25%

Four panels on the left side put inside every cell of first and second columns and set `Dock = Fill`

Two panels on the left side put in the third and forth columns of the first row, set `RowSpan = 2` and `Dock = Fill`

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted, Thank you